# undefined method `permit' for "1":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, strong-parameters

I getting this error when running RSpec and I have no idea what it wants from me? I don't know why it's saying `permit` is undefined? and what is this `1:string` thing happening? If anyone has ideas I'd love to know. Here is my error and code for clarity.

```
CONTROLLER:

  class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
def index
  @subscriber = Subscriber.all
end

def new
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
end

def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save
    flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
    redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

def search
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
end

def visit
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
  if @subscriber
    @subscriber.visit += 1
    @subscriber.save
    flash[:notice] = "thanks"
    redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "search"
  end
end


private

def subscriber_params
 params.require(:subscriber).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
end
end
```

[image]

TEST:

```
  require "rails_helper"

  describe SubscribersController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}


  it "creates a new subscriber" do
    sign_in(user)
    subscriber = FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber)
    expect { post :create, :subscriber =>  subscriber }.to    change(Subscriber, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

SUBSCIRBER OBJECT

[image]
Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Comment: seems that to subscriber var the subsriber is is passed, show params, and valus of a subscriber. You can do it with gem `pry`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you're supplying a ruby object rather than a hash of values when you're submitting your request in the spec. Try using the following instead:

```
subscriber = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:subscriber)
expect { post :create, :subscriber => subscriber }.to ...
```